# Windows registry entry for swapping tilde/backtick and escape keys?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, windows-registry

I have always swapped `CapsLock` and `L-Ctrl`.  I'd like to now swap `Esc` with the `Tilde/Backtick` keys.

What Windows (XP) registry setting do I use for scancode to ensure both of those keys are appropriately swapped?

Comment: *I have always swapped `CapsLock` and `L-Ctrl`* How do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keytweak is also easy to use and effective.

[image]

Comment: I like that it isn't a service or program, but just sets the registry.  Let me take a look.

Comment: This link leads to a version 2.3.1 (latest is 2.3.0) on jaleco.com that gets 20 hits on virustotal.com! A download of 2.3.0 from majorgeeks.com gets zero hits.

Comment: Apparently there is a version 2.3.1. But don't use the one linked to above.

Answer (score 2):

Customize your keyboard layout with the **[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)**.

Comment: Locks up everytime when running under XP (although it said it might when it started).

Answer (score 2):

It appears the actual question was never answered. :)

The registry entry would be:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,3a,00,1d,00,1d,00,\
  3a,00,01,00,29,00,29,00,01,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Note this swaps both ctrl and caps lock, and esc and tilde.